# Ajustar encoding de casos como "Espa\u00f1a" o "Rep\u00fablica de Montenegro"

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-2.x, codificación

Estoy intentando un análisis de sentimientos por país usando python2.7, sobre un fichero json que he obtenido con el API de twitter. 
Mi problema es que a pesar de asignar el encoding por defecto según se sugiere en varios foros, y además realizar el encoding del texto no consigo 'traducir' los caracteres 'raros'.
Asigno encoding por defecto:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Al asignar valores a la variable 'place', si no fuerzo ningún cambio en el encoding, me muestra los caracteres extraños en los nombres de los países resultantes:

```
try:
    jsonLine = json.loads(line)
    place = jsonLine["place"].get('country')
    text = jsonLine["text"]
    score = self.tweet_Score(text, weights)
    yield (place, score)
except:
    pass
```

Ejemplo de Resultado:

"M\u00e9xico"   217.41
"El Salvador"   7.78
"Emirats Arabes Unis"   0
"Espa\u00f1a"   300.62

Si por el contrario hago un decode durante la asignación de valores a 'place' usando .decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8'):

```
try:
    jsonLine = json.loads(line)
    place = jsonLine["place"].get('country').decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
    text = jsonLine["text"]
    score = self.tweet_Score(text, weights)
    yield (place, score)
except:
    pass
```

Usando este último caso, los registros con caracteres extraños desaparecen de mis resultados y dejan de puntuar los valores que tenían calculados (lo que no es correcto).
He probado con diferentes combinaciones de decode y encode, pero los comportamientos son los ya descritos.

Me he planteado la opción de hacer unos `replace` para ajustar los casos más frecuentes, pero no sería apropiado, porque tengo el mismo problema en el contenido de los textos que analizo para puntuar, con lo cual son muchos casos, por lo que supongo que debe existir alguna solución con el encoding, pero ya no sé que más probar.

De antemano gracias por la ayuda!

pd. Para dar información adicional, esta es la pinta que tiene el campo country que estoy usando para el ejemplo, está tomado de mi fichero real de entrada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## La secuencia \u en javascript (y JSON)

Esos "caracteres raros" no son un error. Son la forma en que JSON decide representar los caracteres no-ascii de forma que *no dependan del encoding*.

Me explico, tomando como ejemplo el caso `"España"`. El carácter `"ñ"` no es parte del ASCII por tanto a la hora de introducirlo en una cadena JSON tenemos dos opciones:

1. Elegir un *encoding* que sí tenga el carácter `"ñ"`. Este encóding típicamente será UTF-8 y por tanto Unicode. En Unicode la `"ñ"` tiene el código U+00F1, pero al codificarlo en UTF-8 en el que la unidad básica es el byte, ocupará dos bytes de valores C3 y B1 (hexadecimal). Quien lea esta cadena de caracteres debe saber que el encoding elegido ha sido UTF-8, para poder "reunir" esos dos bytes de nuevo en un sólo caracter (U+00F1) y así obtener la `"ñ"`. Si supone en cambio un encoding como latin1 en que cada byte es un sólo carácter, lo decodificaría errónamente como dos caracteres: `"Ã±"`
2. Elegir representarlo como una secuencia ASCII, que comienza por el carácter de escape `\`. Este carácter se usa para múltiples cometidos, para poder meter en una cadena caracteres que de otra forma no serían visibles o causarían confusión. El caso más típico es `\n` para la nueva-línea, pero tenemos también `\r` para el retorno de carro, `\b` para el "pitido", `\t` para el tabulador, etc... Y el que nos ocupa, `\u` para un carácter unicode. Este debe ir seguido de cuatro dígitos hexadecimales que codifiquen el carácter en cuestión. En nuestro caso por tanto la secuencia de seis caracteres: `\u00f1` representa uno solo: la eñe.

El segundo caso es preferible porque no ha usado ningún *encoding* para almacenar el carácter Unicode, sino que simplemente lo ha representado mediante otra secuencia ASCII. Es como si en HTML hubieses puesto `&#x00f1`, que es también una secuencia ASCII que el navegador mostrará como `ñ`.

El que un texto JSON contenga `"Espa\u00f1a"` no es por tanto ningún problema. Contiene la cadena correcta. Y si un programa JavaScript trata de mostrarla, se verá correctamente la eñe, como puedes comprobar aquí:

```js
console.log("Espa\u00f1a");
```

## La secuencia \u en python2

Esta secuencia para python2 no tiene significado especial. Si en python una cadena contiene `\u00f1`, será mostrado tal cual, como seis caracteres literales:

```
>>> print("Espa\u00f1a")
Espa\u00f1a
```

Pero si se trata de una **cadena unicode** (que lleva una `u` delante de las comillas de apertura), entonces sí es reconocido y tratado:

```
>>> print(u"Espa\u00f1a")
España
```

aunque la forma más habitual en python no es `\u00f1` sino `\xf1`, que también es reconocida:

```
>>> print(u"Espa\xf1a")
España
```

No obstante **cuidado**, cualquiera de estas dos formas guarda dentro de la cadena el carácter Unicode que representa la ñ, y no la secuencia de caracteres `\u00f1` ni `\xf1`. Estas secuencias son procesadas y convertidas al correspondiente carácter. Si quisiéramos guardar esas secuencias en particular, habría que escapar el `\` con otro `\`, para evitar que fuera procesado (y eso guardará en la cadena un único `\`). Así:

```
>>> print(u"Espa\\u00f1a")
Espa\u00f1a
```

La diferencia entre poner una sola `\` o poner dos, es que en el segundo caso el texto resultante no contiene ya ninguna eñe, sino simplemente una secuencia ASCII (de la que forman parte los caracteres `\`, `u`, `0` etc entre otros). Esto se entiende mejor si miras la longitud de estas cadenas:

```
>>> print(len(u"Espa\u00f1a"), len(u"Espa\\u00f1a"))
(6, 11)
```

## JSON y python

Y finalmente llegamos al meollo. Tenemos en JSON una cadena que contiene `\u00f1` que, como hemos visto, es un carácter legal en JSON, y queremos leerla en python. Por ejemplo, hemos leido de un archivo (o de un socket, lo mismo da) la cadena que tenemos guardada en `line`, y que es la siguiente:

```
>>> print(line)

{ "country" : "Espa\u00f1a" }
```

En python 2 la lectura de un archivo (o de un socket) produce un `str`, que es una cadena de bytes, en lugar de una cadena Unicode. Podemos tratar de convertirlo a Unicode, para lo cual generalmente habría que conocer el *encoding* del archivo del cual se ha leido. Pero en este caso, por lo antes dicho, el *encoding* es irrelevante, pues se ha elegido representar la eñe como secuencia ASCII `\uXXXX`. Por tanto lo siguiente deberá funcionar sin errores:

```
>>> print(unicode(line))

{ "country" : "Espa\u00f1a" }
```

Como ves, errores no ha habido, pero tampoco parece que haya funcionado. En realidad sí que ha funcionado (la cadena mostrada ya no es de tipo `str` sino de tipo `unicode`), pero el carácter `\u00f1` no se ha mostrado como esperábamos.

Esto se debe a que lo que tenemos sería el equivalente de haber introducido con `\\u` el texto en Python, pues la cadena que tenemos tiene literalmente un `\` y no un caracter unicode.

Esta última parte puede ser difícil de comprender, pero en realidad no tiene mayor relevancia, ya que lo primero que harás tras recibir una cadena JSON es decodificarla mediante `json.loads()` y este método ya se ocupa de detectar la secuencia `\u` y convertirla al correspondiente carácter python:

```
>>> jsonLine = json.loads(line)
>>> print(jsonLine["country"])
España
```

Por tanto **funciona**.

## ¿Por qué piensas que no te funciona?

Quizás en lugar de imprimir una cadena (como en el ejemplo anterior) estás imprimiendo una estructura de datos, como por ejemplo la variable `jsonLine` resultante. Si haces esto sí que verás *aparentemente* cosas raras:

```
>>> print(jsonLine)
{u'country': u'Espa\xf1a'}
```

Esto se debe a que cuando imprimes un diccionario o una lista, Python te muestra la *representación* de los datos que la componen. Aquí podemos ver por ejemplo que, tanto la clave como el valor son cadenas Unicode (llevan una `u` delante de las comillas). Y dentro de esas cadenas los caracteres no-ascii se están mostrando en su "representación python" (`\xf1`). Pero esto es sólo la forma en que se muestra. Internamente `\xf1` es una `ñ` Unicode, y así se mostrará tan pronto como quieras imprimir esa cadena.

También puede ser que en lugar de imprimir la cadena desde python, estés convirtiendo de nuevo a JSON tus resultados. En ese caso el codificador `json.dumps()` **volverá a codificar** cada carácter no ASCII a la forma estándar JSON que es `\uXXXX`:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(jsonLine))
{"country": "Espa\u00f1a"}
```

pero de nuevo **no hay error** aquí. Es el comportamiento correcto. El JSON así generado es ASCII puro, no depende de encodings, y cuando un cliente JavaScript lo consuma e intente visualizarlo, se verá correctamente `"España"`, mira:

```js
data = "{\"country\": \"Espa\\u00f1a\"}"
parsed = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(parsed)
```

Comment: Gracias por la estupenda explicación @abulafia. Mi código es un mapreduce y el resultado en pantalla es el obtenido por el reducer al hacer `yield (place, score)`, no un print, donde `place = jsonLine["country"]`, por lo que esperaba ver la cadena codificada a utf-8. Entonces, en este caso lo que sucede es que estoy mostrando su "representación python"?, de ser así, una función para 'eliminar acentos'   sería capaz de interpretarlos y tratarlos correctamente verdad?.

Comment: Aunque tu función retorne con `yield` una tupla, en algún momento la imprimirás después para ver que "sale raro", no? O es que esa tupla se usa luego para retornar algún tipo de JSON? Esa es la parte que aún no me quedó clara de tu pregunta, pues si lo imprimieras desde Python deberías ver, o bien `España` (si imprimes la cadena) o bien `u"Espa\xf1a"` (si imprimes su representación), pero no `"Espa\u00f1a"`. Para ver esto último debes haber convertido de nuevo a JSON el resultado, creo yo.

Comment: En realidad no hago print, ni convierto a json, la última instrucción que se ejecuta en el código es el yield de la función de reducer:     `def tweets_reducer_scores(self, word, value):
        yield word, sum(value)` . Donde muestra los caracteres incorrectos es en el resultado de la ejecución en la consola usando: python mapreduceScript.py 'miJson.json' -r inline

Comment: Entonces puede ser cosa del _framework_ en que se ejecuta tu mapreduce, quien quizás convierta a Json el resultado retornado por tu script. Para diagnosticar mejor el problema habría que saber qué framework usas, y ver tu script completo, o un ejemplo de lo que te sale por pantalla.

Comment: Es un ejercicio académico, uso Pycharm para desarrollar y estoy ejecutando el código en local desde la terminal en una maquina con Ubuntu 18.04.1, los resultados con el problema de caracteres se pintan directamente en la Terminal. No sé cuál sería el medio adecuado para que vieras el código y una cata de datos. De momento tengo un workaround (mapeando los nombres desde una tabla de países), a pesar de que tu explicación de codificación me ha aclarado el tema del encoding, me gustaría poder llegar a la razón del problema en este caso puntual.